# Mac Preview resets pdf position to first page always

Tags: mac, pdf, osx-mountain-lion, preview

On Mac, Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8.4), I open a few pdf files with Preview.  I can see all the pdf documents on the left side.  I click on one (say abc.pdf), and then in the reading area I scroll down.  If I then click another file (x.pdf), and then go back to the original (abc.pdf), Preview has automatically scrolled it to the first page.

I searched a bit and was surprised to see no references to a similar issue, which makes me assume that this is not a common problem.  Would you be able to give me any advice on how I can have Preview retain the last read page on each document.

p.s. Only reasonably close wording in the settings is for "On opening new documents: Start on the last viewed page".  And that is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Preview behaves the same way on my installation, so it's probably expected behavior or yet another usability bug in Preview.

You might just open the PDFs in separate windows. Or switch to Skim, which always opens PDFs in separate windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Preview app  on your Mac, choose Preview > Preferences, then click PDF.
2. Select “Use logical page numbers”.

Look at [this Apple guide](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/preview/prvw18524/mac)